# NxN matrix permutations

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, permutation

I have this homework to do for my python class at Uni and I can't get my head around it. Basically I need to write a program that returns an NxN array( preferably using numpy in such a scenario:

```
123456
212345
321234
432123
543212
654321
```

I've attampted to create a simple 6x6 array for example

```
X = np.full((n,n),np.arange(1,+n+1))
```

which returns

```
123456
123456
123456
123456
123456
123456
```

But these are simply permutations of switching the last element with the first and "pushing the ones in the middle to the right but as mentioned earlier its more complex. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Can you come up with a formula for `X[i,j]` in terms of `i` and `j`? (I can, but this is homework!)

If so, you can do:

```
is, js = np.indices((n,n))
X = your_formula(is, js)
```

For example, if you wanted `X[i,j] = i + j`, you could do

```
is, js = np.indices((n,n))
X = is + js
```

Which for `n=3` would give

```
012
123
234
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing loops to solve array problems, you're usually doing it wrong.  Just use an upper triangular matrix.

```
from scipy.linalg import circulant
import numpy as np

>>> arr = circulant(np.arange(1,7)).T
>>> np.triu(arr, 1).T + np.triu(arr)

array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3],
       [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2],
       [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is a homework, I will not give you the complete answer, but I'll give you a tip enough to get you going.

As you have all those numbers, consider putting them into an np.array that way you could use np.reshape(verctor, [lines, columns]). Here's the link to the [Numpy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to do that:

1. Perhaps the most straightforward approach would be that of using [slicings](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?highlight=slicing#slicings) and [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions)

   ```
   def myfunc(n):
       x = range(1, n+1)
       return np.asarray([x[1:i+1][::-1] + x[:n-i] for i in range(n)])
   ```
2. You could also use Matlab-like functions [diag](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html#numpy.diag) and [transpose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html)

   ```
   def myfunc(n):
       x = np.diag(np.ones(n))
       for i in range(2, n+1):
           d = np.diag(i*np.ones(n-i+1), i-1)
           x += d + d.T
       return x
   ```
3. Loop-based solutions - as @GoBrewers14 correctly pointed out - are inefficient for creating large arrays though. In this case you should utilize a **vectorized algorithm** instead. If you don't wish to employ the SciPy's `toeplitz` and `circulant` functions suggested in other answers, [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) is your friend.

   ```
   def myfunc(n):
       x = np.arange(n).reshape((1, n))
       return np.abs(x - x.T) + 1
   ```

And this is what you get by running any of the implementations above:

```
>>> myfunc(6)
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3],
       [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2],
       [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]])
```

Hope this helps

Comment: try `myfunc(10000)` and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very simple and something on my level. I went through the documentation and understood it. I understand the maths behind these kind of problems but I'm just not always sure how to implement it exactly. Cheers again!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not an answer that you can use for your homework, but...

```
In [619]: from scipy.linalg import toeplitz

In [620]: toeplitz(range(1, 7))
Out[620]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3],
       [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2],
       [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]])
```

See the [documentation for `scipy.linalg.toeplitz`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.toeplitz.html) for more information.